# Maximum Size of the SD Card on an Android 2.1 Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

What is the maximum size of the SD Card on an Android Emulator running Android 2.1 ? What is the maximum size one can specify?

Comment: Maybe as big as a FAT32 volume - 32GB
Edit: Actually it could be 4.5GB, as I found somewhere in the web that's a limitation of QEMU

Comment: It makes me wonder why you asked this.

Comment: this question seemed logical because with ever increasing applications and features in the Android arena, one should know the upper limit of available memory before specifying the AVD because many times, the emulator runs out of memory..

Comment: an SD card does not increase the memory available on android, it only increases the storage space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size that a FAT32 volume can be is 8TB. The 32GB limit that ognian mention was a limitation of Windows XP PRE SP3.

The maximum size you will be able to make for the emulator would be 4GB, if you are creating the file on a FAT32 file system. The sdcard volume for the emulator is just a file, and the file size limit on FAT32 is 4GB. If you are using NTFS then you can create it as big as you want.

Now there might be a limitation by the emulator to the 4.5GB that ognian mentioned, but I don't know and I don't have any need to try to create an sdcard volume that large for the emulator.

If you need that much space, maybe your app shouldn't be developed for a mobile device. I can tell you that there is no way I would install an app that said I must have 4.5+ GB of free space on my SD card.

Just so you are clear too, the size of the SD card does not increase the memory available to the device, it only increases the storage space available. Its like comparing [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) and a [Hard Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_drive).

Comment: ok and likewise, whats could be the minimum size of the SD card?

Comment: It would depend on a couple factors, obviously the OS as you see that an OS can have a drive limitation. hardware, I've had devices that only supported 4GB, but a lot support 32GB now or more. And, how the drive is partitioned. The File System could have limitations, like FAT32 is 8TB, so at this moment, if your SD card is FAT32, the biggest it could be is 8TB, but I doubt any mobile hardware supports an 8TB card.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the maximum size (in the "Android SDK Updater version 6") is 2047MB - just under 2GB - entering anything higher than 2047MB for the card size produces an error dialog stating "Error: SD Card size must be at least 9MB".  Is this a bug?